# POJO class to RAML document conversion

Tags: java, raml

I want to convert my pojo classes into a raml document but i am not getting how to do it, is there any existing code for it or not if yes please share the link.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pojo to raml project available here: https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/raml-java-tools/tree/master/pojo-to-raml

```
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
            PojoToRaml pojoToRaml = PojoToRamlBuilder.create();
            Result result = pojoToRaml.classToRaml(MyPojo.class);          
    }
}
```

This will generate the class and dependent classes as RAML 1.0 type declarations.

The default class parsing implementation introspectively looks in your given class and creates properties for fields and RAML superclasses from java superclasses.

If your classes are defined differently, you can create your own implementation of the class parser factory and class parser to do simple discovery in your class.